# Unable to install libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 using yum in redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

While trying to update libxml2 package with libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 in redhat machine, it says the package version is already installed, while when checking the list of installed version of libxml2 the package version is till the old.

`yum install libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64`

`Package libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64 already installed`

`yum list installed libxml2` shows old version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ask yum to update the installed package:

```
yum update libxml2
```

Comment: Does not work for me becuase ```yum info libxml2``` do not list the required package which is libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64. However when i do ```yum info libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64``` it lists the package as available. While when trying to install shows that this version is already installed.

Comment: The issue was my package was already the upgraded version, i had to actually downgrade the version to fix this.